# Hide dropdown menu jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Well I have a simple question for those who knows jQuery. First of all, I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="Layer-69" class="nav-bar nav-links"  >
  <a href="#" title="NOSOTROS" class="nosotros">NOSOTROS</a>
</div>
<div id="nosotros-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="Quienes Somos?">Quienes Somos?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Reseña Historica">Reseña Historica</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Nuestra Filosofia">Nuestra Filosofia</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
   $('.nosotros').on('mouseover', function(){
        $('#nosotros-menu').slideDown('fast');
   });
});
```

What I have right now is that when I put the mouse over the "nosotros" a element, it shows the "nosotros-menu" div element. Now, what I want to do is that when the pointer leaves the "nosotros-menu" div, this div just hide, but I can't do it, I don't know how. please help me, thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
   var timeout = 0;
   $('.nosotros').hover(function(){
        $('#nosotros-menu').slideDown('fast');
   },function(){
         timeout = setTimeout(hideMenu,300);
    });

   $("#nosotros-menu").hover(function(){
       clearTimeout(timeout);
   },function(){
       hideMenu();
   });
});

function hideMenu(){
    $("#nosotros-menu").slideUp('fast');
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It worked!... I really appreciate this. But I just have another question, it work when I hover over the #nosotros-menu element, but when I just hover over the .nosotros element the #nosotros-menu stays there until I hover it and after that it hide.

Comment: You might also look into the hover intent plugin, this will handle the  delay for you so that you dont need to do the timeout part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the mouseover event, bind to the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event. With hover, you supply two functions, one for when the user's mouse enters, and one for when it leaves, and jquery wires it up for you. Inside the first function, do the slideDown action, then in the second one, the slideUp action.

Comment: Could you explain it a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You can do just like that:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
   $('.nosotros').hover(
     function () {
       $('#nosotros-menu').slideDown('fast');
     }, 
     function () {
       $('#nosotros-menu').slideUp('fast');
     }
   );
});
```